# Check if a list contains any element of another list in Dart

Tags: dart

I have an array:

```dart
const list1 = [0, 1, 2];
```

How do I check if other arrays contain any of the target array elements?

For example:

```dart
[2, 3] //returns true;

[2, 3, 4] //returns true;

[3, 4] //returns false;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `list1.indexWhere(list2.contains)` should be fine for small lists, but for *large* lists, the asymptotic runtime complexity would be O(m * n) where *m* and *n* are the sizes of the lists.

A different way to pose the problem of checking if a list contains any element of another list is to check if the set-intersection of two lists is non-empty.  The direct way to implement that would be:

```dart
var contains = list1.toSet().intersection(list2.toSet()).isNotEmpty;
```

Since the default `Set` implementation is a `LinkedHashSet`, lookups would be O(1), and computing the intersection would be linear with respect to one of the `Set`s.  However, converting each `List` to a `Set` would take linear time, making the whole operation take O(m + n).

That's asymptotically efficient, but it computes the entire intersection just to determine whether it's empty or not, which is wasteful.  You can do a bit better by using `.any` to stop earlier and noting that `.any` doesn't benefit from the receiving object being a `Set`:

```dart
var set2 = list2.toSet();
var contains = list1.any(set2.contains);
```

Note that if you can use `Set`s in the first place instead of `List`s, then the conversion cost would disappear and make the operation O(m).

Answer (score 1):

```dart
final contains = list1.indexWhere((e) => list2.contains(e)) > -1
```

##### Explanation

[`indexWhere`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html) returns an index of an element where the test function returned `true`.

[`contains`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html) returns `true` if the given element is presented in the array.

Comment: You can even reduce it to: `final contains = list1.indexWhere(list2.contains) > -1;` :)

Comment: Using a `Set` would be more efficient if you have many items: `final contains = iterable.any(set.contains);`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Why it is more efficient? And wouldn't converting the list to set eat up all the performance gain?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev `List.contains` is O(n) but `Set.contains` is O(1).  With two `List`s of length *m* and *n*, your approach would be O(m * n).  If one of them is already a `Set`, then the whole operation would be O(m), and even if you had to convert one to a `Set` first, it would be O(m + n).